# Train and test split has header and index names missing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, scikit-learn

I am splitting a dataset in train and test set using,

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X.values, y.values, test_size = 0.20, random_state=99)
```

However the train & test sets have no column names and index names after the split. How to restore this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
X_names = X.columns
y_name = y.name

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X.values, y.values, \
                                                    test_size = 0.20, random_state=99)
```

Store the names before performing the split (assuming that X and y are pandas objects). Alternatively, you don't even need to pass in X.values and y.values. Instead, you could just pass in X and y. This way you will maintain the pandas data structure.

Comment: for X and y ,X_names = X.columns    y_names=y.columns ??

Comment: y is not a dataframe. y is a single column which in terms of pandas is known as a series. So, you could find the name of the series using .name. But, in the case of X, X is a dataframe (multiple series make a df). So, you would need to do X.columns in this case.

Comment: after scalar fit transform , again the column names and index name are missing !

Comment: Please edit your post and include your code. It is difficult to assess what you are doing prior to the train test split. I think you are mixing up your pandas and numpy data structures. These structures integrate well with each other, but you need to know how to go back and forth. So, if you want to go from numpy to pandas, the easiest would be to reassign the column names to the numpy array when casting as a pandas dataframe. Again, I will need to see your code to direct you.

Comment: Update your initial question with the code in the proper format. This is not the proper way to write code.